# Misplaced \omit - despise \muticolumn has been placed at the beginning of the row

Tags: multicolumn

I am trying to compile an automated catalogue and I have a problem using `xtabular`. Here is a compilable MWE, that does not have any header. This example does compile:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,table]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=307mm,paperwidth=220mm,top=30mm,bottom=25mm,footskip=10mm,headsep=15mm,left=16mm,right=16mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{placeins}
%\usepackage[maxfloats=1000]{morefloats}
\usepackage[pages=all, placement=top]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat} %% Option 'defaultfam'
%% only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\fontfamily{Montserrat-TOsF}\selectfont #1}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{1c6fa9}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xtab}
%\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{datetime}
%\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{U+52}{è}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\noindent

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{xtabular}{p{48px} p{50px} p{122px} p{37px}}
    \tablefirsthead{\rowcolor{mycolor}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline}
    \tablehead{\rowcolor{mycolor}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline}
    \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\scriptsize{\textbf{23352}} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\tiny{735452143} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots\\
    \FloatBarrier
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{xtabular}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

However, as you can see if you compile the code above, the double header that I want for my table, that is laid out on two columns, and spans multiple pages, does not appear in the first column, first page of the table. For this reason, I repeat the following block of the two lines header:

```
\rowcolor{mycolor}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline
```

Obtaining:

```
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{xtabular}{p{48px} p{50px} p{122px} p{37px}}
    \tablefirsthead{\rowcolor{mycolor}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline}
    \tablehead{\rowcolor{mycolor}
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
        \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline}
    \rowcolor{mycolor}
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
    \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline
    \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\scriptsize{\textbf{23352}} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\tiny{735452143} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots\\
    \FloatBarrier
    \vspace{1mm}
\end{xtabular}
\end{multicols*}
```

It is straightforward to verify that in this case the instruction `\rowcolor{mycolor}` will generate a `Misplaced \noalign` because of the prerogative requested by `multicolumn` that wants to be the first command in any cell. Beside this, anyways, a `Misplaced \omit. ...\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}}` appears. Can someone please explain the source of the last error and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for your answer, David, though this answer does not explain two things:

1. why if I move around the code it does compile perfectly? i.e.

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt,twoside,table]{book}
   \usepackage[paperheight=307mm,paperwidth=220mm,top=30mm,bottom=25mm,footskip=10mm,headsep=15mm,left=16mm,right=16mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
   \usepackage{placeins}
   %\usepackage[maxfloats=1000]{morefloats}
   \usepackage[pages=all, placement=top]{background}
   \usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc}
   \usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat} %% Option 'defaultfam'
   %% only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[italian]{babel}
   \renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\fontfamily{Montserrat-TOsF}\selectfont #1}}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{calc}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
   \definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{1c6fa9}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \usepackage{changepage}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{colortbl}
   \usepackage{xtab}
   %\usepackage{supertabular}
   \usepackage{datetime}
   %\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{U+52}{è}
   \usepackage{microtype}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}

   \begin{document}
   \noindent

   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}

   \begin{multicols*}{2}
   \begin{xtabular}{p{48px} p{50px} p{122px} p{37px}}
       \rowcolor{mycolor}
       \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
           \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
           \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline
       \tablefirsthead{\rowcolor{mycolor}
           \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
           \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
           \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline}
       \tablehead{\rowcolor{mycolor}
           \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{MERCEDES-BENZ}}} & \textcolor{white}{p.}\\
           \multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{\textbf{500 / 595 / 695 (312\_)}} \,\,\,\,\tiny{\textbf{8.2008 - }}}\\
           \arrayrulecolor{mycolor}\hline}



   \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\scriptsize{\textbf{23352}} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\tiny{735452143} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots\\
   \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\scriptsize{\textbf{23352}} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\tiny{735452143} & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots & \cellcolor{mycolor!20}\ldots\\
   \FloatBarrier
   \vspace{1mm}
   \end{xtabular}
   \end{multicols*}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. why when I repeat the xtabular by stacking multiple of these environments the heading is omitted from the first instance but it is placed in the following ones?

Comment: the misplaced omit error is as you say coming from `\multicolumn` as it isn't the first item in a cell.

Comment: thank you for your answer: I edit the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

`\tablehead` is apparently written so that `\multicolumn` (or noalign constructs such as `\rowcolor`) can't follow. The slightly hacky but simplest way to avoid the issue is to give it a blank row to work on, just insert

```
\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
```

before the `\rowcolor`